# Need clarification on the paragraph

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

We regard the set N of natural numbers as a subset of $R$, by identifying the natural number
$n \in N$ with the n-fold sum of the unit element $1 \in R$ Similarly, we identify $0 \in Z$ with the
zero element of $0 \in R$ , and we identify the n-fold sum of $-1$ with the integer $-n$. Thus,we consider $N$ and $Z$ to be subsets of $R$.

This paragraph is from "Introduction to Real Analysis  Fourth Edition by Robert G. Bartle, Donald R. Sherbert". Don't quite grasp the idea behind the n-fold sum and how it lead to the conclusion that $N$ and  $Z$ are subsets of $R$ .

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  As a field, $\mathbb R$ has  $1$ and therefore also $1+1+\cdots1$, so all counting numbers

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I think I get the idea.